# Syntax error in FROM clause using ADOTable

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7, adoconnection

I'm trying to link a ms-access doc to Delphi 7 using a ADOconnection, ADOTable, Datasource and DBGrid.
I have connected everything to each other. 
If I set the ADOTable to `Active=True` an error message is showing

> Syntax Error in FROM clause

I have done this before and no error messages has appeared. The fields in my ms-access table are:

- ID (autonumber)
- Email (text)
- Password (number)

Comment: Are you using `TableDirect`?  What is the table name you want to use with your ADOTable?

Comment: Looks like your tablename is a reseved word you might use an Adodataset with a CommandText like `Select * from [national]` where national would be an exmaple for a reserved name.

Comment: `Password` is a reserved word and triggers syntax errors in Access queries run on an ADO connection.  However I know neither Delphi nor sufficient details about how you're interacting with the Access db.  So just as a wild guess, I suggest you enclose the field name in square brackets ... `[Password]` ... and see whether that change eliminates the Access syntax error.

Comment: For more on reserved words, see the following link: http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html